# Adding class with the same value as selector

Tags: angular, sonarqube

To fix some issues with SonarQube (namely, "Unexpected unknown type selector"), I'm trying to add a class to every component I have in my webapp. For example, I want my components to be `<app-footer class="app-footer">` so I can use class selectors instead of tags.

What could be the best approach?

I could go and modify each component and ad host.class property and add the same value as the 'selector' property, but is there a better way where I don't have to replicate the selector name or have to manually modify each component?

Answer (score 0):

You could set specific attributes for test like data-test-tag , so you need not modify the classes. You can query the dom using [data-test-tag='app-footer'] for testing

```html
<app-footer data-test-tag="app-footer">
```